# A lateral differentiable function and a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an open iterval, be a function that admits lateral derivatives at each point in $I$. Is the following set countable:

$J=\{x\in I\ |\ f'_{+}(x)\neq f'_{-}(x)\}$

?

By lateral derivatives, I mean:

$f'_{+}(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0, x>x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ and

$f'_{-}(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0, x<x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$.

Comment: @5xum I suppose it refers to one-sided derivative.

Comment: Is $I$ just any set or is it an open set?

Comment: @WillardZhan I see that now since the question was edited.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: A more general result can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128806/real-valued-function-of-one-variable-which-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-semi-diffe/128820#128820).

Comment: @WillardZhan Thanks a lot. Now I understand!